# Exception caught by image resource service

Tags: flutter, dart

Exception caught by image resource service 
I am getting error while running the following code.

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('PITCH'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('WELCOME'),
            new Image(image: AssetImage('download.png'))
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

**Error:**

> flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   flutter: The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
>   flutter: Unable to load asset: download.png
>   flutter:
>   flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   flutter: #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
>   flutter: 
>   flutter: #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:44)
>   flutter: 
>   flutter: #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:449:14)
>   flutter: #3      ImageProvider.resolve... (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:316:48)
>   flutter: #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
>   flutter: #5      ImageProvider.resolve.. (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:316:25)
>   flutter: (elided 13 frames from package dart:async)
>   flutter:
>   flutter: Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "download.png")
>   flutter: Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#ea200(), name: "download.png", scale:
>   flutter:   1.0)

Comment: Make sure you stop the app process and then run the app again (full start)

Answer (score 3):

This might be because of following reasons.

1. You forgot to add the asset in `pubspec.yaml` file
2. You forgot to run `flutter packages get` command.
3. You did a hot restart/reload of the app.

Comment: what if the images are requested to load dynamically through device after run?

Comment: Glad to hear it, don't forget to mark the answer accepted. See how to accept an answer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGwTL.png)

Comment: Thank you! This - You did a hot restart/reload of the app - saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure these following things:

- you've declared full path of the image in your pubspec.yaml file.
- Run `flutter pub get` after declaring the asset images.
- Write full path in the code just as you wrote in pubspec.yaml. So it should be `'assets/download.png'`